# Why are my clothes hot after washing them?

Tags: washing-machine

My new LG frontload washer leaves my clothes HOT after each cycle. The hot water valve has been turned off and it is still leaving them hot. Any suggestions?

Comment: Maybe you swapped the hot and cold water supplies.

Comment: Steven, that is a possibility. Movers hooked it back up for me when I moved and it was doing fine until then. I just can't understand why its still leaving the clothes very HOT when i cut the hot water supply off.

Comment: These new washers can be pretty sophisticated. Since they use minimal water, I would not be surprised that they have a heater to maintain the set temperature. I assume you are not using the hot setting? If I'm right, the thermostatic heat control could be defective. But this is all conjecture on my part.

Answer (score 4):

If you're not selecting a hot water cycle, then you probably have the hot and cold water lines hooked up backwards. Or the hot and cold taps are labeled incorrectly. Next time you run a load, touch the water lines or the fittings to feel their temperature. If the cold water line is hotter than the hot water line, then you should be able to find the problem.